# Add a fake bluetooth device without having a module itself

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I need to create an application which will work with some medical bluetooth devices. In fact, currently I do not need any real devices, but I need them to be in the Windows 7 Devices list. Also, there is no a bluetooth module installed on my working machine.

So, the question is:
Is it possible to add a fake/virtual device(s) into the system?
If yes, then is it possible to make them of a specific type, e.g. any kind of blood pressure measurement device etc.?